# Xaml data-binding stringformat won't work

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui

I'm trying to display two lables with binded values + some static text and want to see a final result like `~50% Completed` and `(stopped)` but what I see is `100` and `Stopped` respectively. but the strange thing happens when I make any small changes in it (e.g. `~{0}% Not Completed`) **and Hot-Reload it**, it displays what I want without any issue, but after reopening the app again it won't display what I want.

```xml
<Label
    Text="{Binding Speed, StringFormat=~{0}% Completed}"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    FontSize="Body"
    Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
<Label
    Text="{Binding Status, StringFormat=({0})}"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    FontSize="Body"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior indeed. I could replicate that error(ish) also. But good news, you could work with converters for your purpose.

Create a folder inside your maui project named `Converters`

Create these 2 classes

**SpeedConverter.cs**

```
namespace MauiApp.Converters;

class SpeedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string speed = (string)value;
        return $"~{speed}% Completed";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**StatusConverter.cs**

```
class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string status = (string)value;
        return $"({status})";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now in you XAML file, import that namespace

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Converters">
```

And change your label's text bindings like this

```
<Label
  Margin="0,0,5,0"
  FontAttributes="Bold"
  FontSize="Body"
  HorizontalOptions="Center"
  Text="{Binding Speed, Converter={converters:SpeedConverter}}" />
        
<Label
  FontAttributes="Bold"
  FontSize="Body"
  HorizontalOptions="Center"
  Text="{Binding Status, Converter={converters:StatusConverter}}" />
```